# Values for asterisks incorrectly placed on heat map

Tags: r, p-value, complexheatmap

I want to put asterisks in the heat map for P-values < 0.05. I have a separate spreadsheet with the P-values that I read into R and subsequently the heat map, however, the function i'm using doesn't seem to place the asterisks in the right cells. In the Figure below, for example, there are no P-values attached to the rho = 0 cells, and yet there are asterisks placed there.

[image]

Spreadsheet is shown below. For all P-values that are NA, I put in "1" to avoid an error. If there's a better way to do this on top of fixing the placements of the asterisks, please let me know.
[image]

The code that i'm using is as follows:

```
library(circlize)
library(ComplexHeatmap)
library(Hmisc)

sx_syn_p <- read.csv('spear_synx1_p.csv', header=TRUE)

Shime1x_syn_spearman1 <- Heatmap(sx_syn, circlize::colorRamp2(c(-1, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 1), 
                                                                        c('#d7191c', '#fdae61',
                                                                          '#FFFFFF', '#abd9e9', 
                                                                          '#2c7bb6')),
                                column_names_gp=grid::gpar(fontsize=20,
                                                           col=c(rep('#4daf4a', 8), rep('#984ea3',7))),
                                row_names_gp=grid::gpar(fontsize=20, 
                                                        col=c(rep('#4daf4a', 8), rep('#984ea3',7))),
                                heatmap_legend_param=list(title="Spearman's rho", 
                                                          direction='horizontal',
                                                          at = c(-1, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 1)),
                   cell_fun = function(j, i, x, y, w, h, fill){
                     if(sx_syn_p[i, j] < 0.05) {
                       grid.text('*', x, y)
                     }
                   })
sx_syn1_spear <- draw(Shime1x_syn_spearman1, heatmap_legend_side='top')
```

I thought the function inputs asterisks based on P < 0.05 from the spreadsheet, but the inputs does not seem to be placed correctly.

Comment: Can you make a small reproducible example (say, 3x3) and share the data in a copy/pasteable way rather than as a picture of a spreadsheet?

Comment: Sorry, yes I will do that next time. I found a way to fix it on my end that I'll post as a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix this by removing the first column of labels in the spreadsheet and re-running the code. I think that converting the data frame as a matrix would give further assurance per [this example](https://gist.github.com/jokergoo/ac65ed4061c83fe26a4a3e182c9cb6f9). The issue with my code was that the order of `sx_syn` was not the same as `sx_syn_p`.

Comment: can you show dataframe i mean dput as I would like to use the same

Comment: Hey, I've uploaded the sample data I worked with [here](https://github.com/ake700/MSc-sample-codes/blob/main/R/spear_prox1_r.csv). The code for making the heat map with asterisks is in there too if you go one folder back.

To convert the data frame into a matrix, I just did:
```df_matx <- as.matrix(df[,2:16], 'numeric') #note that the values indicate columns```

Comment: just curious these are metabolite data?

Comment: These are metabolites and microbiota (16S rRNA) sequences